Typescript React Route is Requiring Prop Declared In Another Component
I'm currently refactoring my application to incorporate TypeScript and I'm having some issues with React Router. I'm receiving the following error.

Property 'toggleCreateForm' is missing in type '{}' but required in
type 'FormProps'.

From what I can tell this is because I'm not passing my custom hook into the Routes element as a prop, but I don't think I should have to do this as the hook is declared in another component and managed by that state. It seems counterintuitive that I would need to duplicate this.
App.tsx
function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const token = useAppSelector(selectToken);
  const currentUser = useAppSelector(selectCurrentUser);
  const isAuthenticated = useAppSelector(selectAuthenticated);
  
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  
  const checkLoggedIn = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    dispatch(userCheckLoggedIn());
    setIsLoading(false)
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  useEffect(() => { 
    checkLoggedIn()
  }, [checkLoggedIn])
  
  console.debug(
    "App",
    "currentUser", currentUser,
    "token=", token
  )
    
  // Find current user using local storage "token"

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingComponent/>
  } else {
    if (!(token && isAuthenticated)) {
      return (
        <div className="">
          <NavBar></NavBar>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/register" element={<SignupForm/>}/>
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<Homepage/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar></NavBar>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/workouts" element={<WorkoutList/>}/>
            <Route path="/workouts/:workout_id" element={<WorkoutDetail/>}/>
            <Route path="/workouts/add" element={<NewWorkoutForm/>}/>
            <Route path="/register" element={<SignupForm/>}/>
            <Route path="/exercises" element={<ExerciseList/>}/>
            <Route path="/exercises/add" element={<NewExerciseForm/>}/>
            <Route path="/account" element={<Account/>}/>
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;

NewWorkoutForm.tsx
interface FormValues {
  name: string,
  category: number
};

interface Category {
  id: number,
  user_id: number
  name: string,
  systemdefault: boolean
};

interface FormProps{
  toggleCreateForm(): boolean
}

const NewWorkoutForm = ({toggleCreateForm} : FormProps): React.JSX.Element => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const categories = useAppSelector(selectCategories);
    const currentUser = useAppSelector(selectCurrentUser);

    const categoryComponents : object[] = categories.map( (cat : Category) => (
        <option value={cat.id}>{cat.name}</option>
    ))

    return (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <Card className="w-25 d-flex flex-column align-items-center pb-3">
                <h3>New Workout Form</h3>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        name: '', 
                        category: 1,
                        }}
                    validate={(values: FormValues) => {
                        const errors: FormikErrors<FormValues> = {};
                        if (!values.name){ errors.name = 'Name Required'}
                        return errors
                    }}

                    onSubmit={(values : FormValues, { setSubmitting } : FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
                        setTimeout( async () => {
                            dispatch(addWorkout({
                                ...values,
                                user_id: currentUser.id,
                                favorited: false
                            }))
                            setSubmitting(false);
                            toggleCreateForm();
                        }, 400)
                    }}
                    >
                        {({isSubmitting}) => (
                            <div>
                            <Form>
                                <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center row-gap-3">    
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-between row-gap-3">

                                    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                                        <label htmlFor="name">Workout Name:</label>
                                        <Field type='name' name='name'/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style={{color: "red"}}>
                                        <ErrorMessage name='name' component='div'/>
                                </div>
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                                        <label htmlFor="category">Workout Category:</label>
                                        <Field as='select' name='category'>
                                            {categoryComponents}
                                        </Field>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style={{color: "red"}}>
                                        <ErrorMessage name='category' component='div'/>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-row column-gap-5">
                                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={toggleCreateForm}>Cancel</button>
                                        <button className="btn btn-success" type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>Create Workout</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Form>
                            </div>
                        )}
                </Formik>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewWorkoutForm;

toggleCreateForm is a custom hook that is passed into the NewWorkoutForm
const [showCreateWorkoutForm, setShowCreateWorkoutForm] = useToggle();

const toggleCreateForm = () => { 
  setShowCreateWorkoutForm()
}

This was working prior to TypeScript.

element={<NewWorkoutForm />} -> You are obviously not passing any props here, so if toggleCreateForm is a non-optional prop then it must be passed.

I think you just need to edit your interface so the toggle function is not required
interface FormProps {
  toggleCreateForm?: () => boolean
}

